# How to make a multi-site instance aware of shared module directory?

Tags: 7

My team inherited a Drupal 7 multi-site installation that was originally built with a custom installation profile and Drush make. I have all these sites running correctly in our environment now and want to bring an additional Drupal 7 standalone instance we support under this new multi-site configuration. I copied the database and created a corresponding subdirectory in the sites tree along with the proper edits to the sites.php file. The site does appear correctly when tested in a browser but the modules visible to the other instances are not seen by this site. Those modules are located under the profiles tree. I don't expect to need to use the install profile again and am inclined to copy the profiles/myprofile/modules directory contents to sites/all/modules to address this situation but am concerned about potential database dependencies. What is the best way to clean this up and have all multi-site instances aware of the same common modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way...Run

```
variable_set('install_profile', 'name_of_custom_install_profile');
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

from somewhere in the new site.

That'll trick your new site into thinking it was installed with the custom profile, and it should start checking that folder for contrib modules.

Comment: I added this code to settings.php in the new site directory and received the following error upon refresh:                         Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_merge() in /Sites/drupal7/prod_multi/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 999

Comment: Yeah settings.php won't work as it's included too early on in the bootstrap...the DB functions aren't loaded yet. Either install the Devel module and run the code at /devel/php, or put it in a module hook or your theme's template.php file

Comment: Is this something I need to execute one time only or does it need to remain in the code?

Comment: It just needs to execute once

Comment: Executing via devel module did the trick. Thanks! Note that there is a typo in the second line of your code. I will accept this answer.

Comment: So there is, sorry about that :)